# NodeJS and PCAP, ignore packets send by PCAP

Tags: node.js, linux, packet, pcap, libpcap

I have the following code for sniffing and sending `packets` with `PCAP`, if the `source address` is matching a specific one:

```
var Cap = require('cap').Cap;
var decoders = require('cap').decoders;
var PROTOCOL = decoders.PROTOCOL;

var c = new Cap();
var device = Cap.findDevice('192.168.0.10');
var filter = 'net 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0';
var bufSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(65535);

var linkType = c.open(device, filter, bufSize, buffer);

c.setMinBytes && c.setMinBytes(0);

c.on('packet', function(nbytes, trunc) {

  // raw packet data === buffer.slice(0, nbytes)

  if (linkType === 'ETHERNET') {
    var ret = decoders.Ethernet(buffer);

    if (ret.info.type === PROTOCOL.ETHERNET.IPV4) {
      ret = decoders.IPV4(buffer, ret.offset);

      if (ret.info.srcaddr === '192.168.10.10') {
        try {
          bufferToSend = buffer.slice(0, nbytes);
          // TODO, this packet will be catched by pcap and resend again and again and again
          c.send(bufferToSend, bufferToSend.length);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Error sending packet:", e);
        }
      }

    } else
      console.log('Unsupported Ethertype: ' + PROTOCOL.ETHERNET[ret.info.type]);
  }
});
```

The code works, but there's a catch which is that the `packet` I'm sending out gets sniffed once again with `PCAP`, and creates a `loop`.

I'm running `Node.JS` and `cap` module.

Is there a good way to overcome this issue?

Comment: A suggestion. libpcap supports installing filters in the capture interfaces, so you could easily remove most of the code, and as a side-effect make it more efficient.
See https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap for the Node specifics and https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html for the actual format.
With the right filter your callback should only contain the `try-catch` block.

Comment: Oh, I see you're using a filter for some of the properties. Why didn't you go all the way?

Comment: What does the program attempt to do? Do you really want to duplicate the packet, or just let it through? If the latter is true, you don't need to inject, sniffing with libpcap doesn't interfere with the normal path of packet processing, e.g., you won't be starving your browser.